# Fixed a header with a FragmentList and with dynamic contents

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, header

I'm trying to fixed the header of a list with a dynamic contents in my app. The problem is I only see the header but not contents. If I commented some lines the list contents appears but the header not. I try using the `addHeader` but it makes the header not fixed.

**My controller**

```
public class RadioListFragment extends ListFragment {
    /** The Radios. */
    private ArrayList<Radio> mRadios;

    /** The Header view. */
    private View mHeaderView;

    /** The Radio adapter. */
    private RadioAdapter mRadioAdapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mRadios = RadioRepo.get(getActivity()).getRadios();
        mRadioAdapter = new RadioAdapter(mRadios);

        setListAdapter(mRadioAdapter);
    }

    @TargetApi(11)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header_radio, parent, false);
        //mHeaderView = v.findViewById(R.id.list_header_radioTextView);

        // Inflate the Header View
        /*
        mHeaderView = (View)getActivity()
                .getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.list_header_radio, null, false);
        */

        return v;
    }


    private class RadioAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Radio> {

        public RadioAdapter(ArrayList<Radio> radios) {
            super(getActivity(), 0, radios);
        } 

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_item_radio, null);
            }

            // Configure the view for this Radio
            Radio r = getItem(position);
            TextView nameTextView = 
                    (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_list_item_nameTextView);
            nameTextView.setText(r.getName());
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

**list_header_radio.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_header_radioTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/dummy_text_view" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_item_radio.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/radio_list_item_logoImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/radio_list_item_nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/radio_list_item_logoImageView"
        android:text="@string/radios_name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your ListView as this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/list_header_radioTextView" />
```

And you can get your header view as your commented line:

```
mHeaderView = v.findViewById(R.id.list_header_radioTextView);
```

Comment: Bang. I never thought it was so easy to fixed. Haha. Thank you buddy.